# awk + how to perform OR in awk

Tags: linux, awk, disk-usage

by the following command I capture available size from df

```
echo "$DF" | awk '$NF == "/var" { print $(NF-2) }'
```

how to set the syntax if I want to set

```
NF == "/var"
```

or

```
NF == "/"
```

because I want to capture also the "/" additional to /var (sometimes /var is under / )

I tried:

```
 echo "$DF" | awk '$NF == "/var|/" { print $(NF-2) }'
```

but isn't working.

Comment: On a GNU system, you can also do `df --output=avail / /var | tail -n +2`

Comment: Or `stat -fc '%a * %s / 1024' / /var | bc` (still on a GNU system, also in KiB (for GNU df, whether it's in KiBs or half-KiBs depends on whether there's a POSIXLY_CORRECT variable in the environment, best it to add a `-k` option to make sure you always get KiBs))

Comment: FYI `df --output=target,size  / /var | uniq | awk 'NR>1 {print $2}'` - with GNU `df`, that will print the size(s) of both `/` and `/var` if they are separate filesystems, or just `/` if not.  The `NR>1` in awk skips `df`'s header line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do this:

```
echo "$DF" | awk '$NF == "/var" || $NF == "/" { print $(NF-2) }'
```

or if you want to use a regex, use the `~` regex matching operator:

```
echo "$DF" | awk '$NF ~ "^(/var|/)$" { print $(NF-2) }'
```

or:

```
echo "$DF" | awk '$NF ~ "^/(var)?$" { print $(NF-2) }'
```